# Date format can't be handled as date

Tags: python

Please any help I got the following error while `type( df1['Date'])` is class `pandas.core.series.Series` and df1['Date'][0] is float:

`AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'toordinal'`

```
 for i in range(2266,df1.shape[0],1):

            performance[i]=performance[i-1]*(1+r[i])
 df1['performance']=performance
 print(performance[2267])
 plt.plot(df1['Date'][2265:4616],df1['performance'][2265:4616])
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide a [mcve]. This includes correctly formatted code, full traceback and a minimal example that demonstrates the problem you see.

Comment: the error is related to my excel file from where i read the data . Jupyter  notebook read the date format as 'pandas.core.series.Series' from which i got the error

Comment: The indentation is incorrect

Comment: Thanks but it correct my error is with the date format 'int' object has no attribute 'toordinal'

Comment: this is a print of the date i have 2265    2009-01-02 00:00:00
2266    2009-01-05 00:00:00
2267    2009-01-06 00:00:00
2268    2009-01-07 00:00:00
2269    2009-01-08 00:00:00